# UITableViewController with Search in Popover has odd animation

Tags: ios, navigation, uitableview, uipopovercontroller, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a popover with a UITableViewController in it.

I am getting a strange behavior where the search bar over compensates like it's expecting a status bar...

[image: Simulator frame offset]

I've tried to inspect the frame but i'm not seeing any offsets. Is anyone having this problem? I have a custom navigation bar under it with a segmented control inside it.

Going to try to make a sample application later to see if it's a limit of the OS (yet another bug with popover and navigation bar

In a sample application I get the same results. With a normal UINavigationBar

Comment: I've sent a sample application to apple as a defect when putting a navigation controller with searchDisplayController on a table view in a popover. Seems iOS 7 has this issue only. I've tried a lot of stuff to fix this. I tried to set the navigationBar to opaque and tried to move the frame of the search bar to a better location but that is just a hack. It snaps into place and then the touch area it uses is all screwed up if you move it after it snaps.

Answer (score 2):

I unchecked the "Under Top Bars" option in the "View Controller" section of my table view controller. Works for me now. (assuming you're using Interface Builder, like I do)

Comment: This fixes part of the issue. However, there's still a snappy feel to the ui there which does not feel native at all.